# debug key to MD5 (for Google Maps tutorial) not working with my Terminal?

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm trying to follow the google maps tutorial, but i need to use a debug key, i followed the instructions but when i write the command lines it does not work : the Terminal (on Mac) says "command not found" to this :

```
$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore /Users/Paul/.android/debug.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

Could you help me?

here's the link : http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try this change your directory to 

 C:>cd C:\Program Files\Java\\bin 
in my case it is **C:>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin** 
now use this

> *keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\**username**\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android*

If you still cant get it,  check the [Tutorial here](http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/01/creating-md5-key-for-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

the keytool binary is located in your `<JAVA_INSTALL_DIR>bin` directory. Check to see if it is in your path.

Comment: thanks, i have no idea where this is, i've got "eclipse" , "workspace" (for android) and "android" in the same folder. But i can't find a "bin" in those folders, can you help me out?

Comment: It is located somewhere in your file system. On windows computers, in a directory called "program files". I am sure there is a counterpart on macs.

Comment: thanks Glenn, well 1. i've got a bin in Developer > usr > bin, that contains tons of "program" files, but i did not find anything for me... also, it seems that i have a problem with the Terminal, it should at least "respond" to my command lines, but to put "3 lines" like that, seems to crash it... do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

try like this..

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin>keytool.exe -V -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\IBM\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

you ll get all the key values.